# debugging two separate applications, angular and web API

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I have two separate applications, one is angular and another one is in web API. I have a function in angular and that functions in turn calls a method in .net core. Is it possible to debug the function in angular and then transfer the debugger to .net core so my angular code is below::

angular function:

```
onSubmit() {
  if (this.service.form.valid) {
    this.service.AddProjectDetails(this.service.form.value);
    this.service.form.reset();
    this.service.initializeFormGroup();
  }
}

  AddProjectDetails(project: AllItProject) {
    const httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) };
    return this.http.post<AllItProject>(ROOT_URL + '/PostAllItProjectsList/',
    AllItProject, httpOptions);

}
```

and the web API method PostAllItProjectsList is defined in .net side:

// POST: api/AllItProjectsLists

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<AllItProjectsList>> PostAllItProjectsList(AllItProjectsList allItProjectsList)
{
    _context.AllItProjectsList.Add(allItProjectsList);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetAllItProjectsList", new { id = allItProjectsList.ProjectId }, allItProjectsList);
}
```

when I start debugging the typescript. The debugger goes to this line:

```
return this.http.post<AllItProject>(ROOT_URL + '/PostAllItProjectsList/',
```

and then it does not get transferred to PostAllItProjectsList. How can I transfer the debugger to PostAllItProjectsList.
The port # for angular side is 4200 and the port # for web API side is

```
https://localhost:44328/api/
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just put a breakpoint in `PostAllItProjectsList`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are asking is for **AngularCliServer** in .netcore

What you need to do is:

Add Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions nuget package.

And then configure in you Startup.cs the **Angular Cli** like:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

app.UseMvc(routes =>
 {
    routes.MapRoute(name: "default",emplate: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
```

**Important**:

> To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,  see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

This allows you to have if you want angular running on separate port or the same port as your .net core app.

Comment: Thank You!! Your answer is perfect. I read the Microsoft article too and was able to break at my .net code. Thank You again!!